# laravel сохранить выбранное значение не числом

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel5

при сохранении данных значения улица и город сохраняются в качестве идентификатора а не значения,как решить эте проблему ?.У меня есть 2 связанных выподающих списка, когда я заполняю форму затем  сохроняю, значение сохраняестся в качестве номера а мне необходимо значение (название).

Таблица заказов

```
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->until }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->my_arrival }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->hour_for_guests }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->elevator }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->_parking    }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->private }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->floor }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->flat }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->entrance }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->street }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->b_number }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->place }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->tel_2 }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->tel_1 }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->name_f_l }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->celivery_type }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->city }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->day }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{ $order->date }}</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap text-center">{{$order->id }}</th>
```

Контроллер заказов

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function AddNewOrder( OrderValidatorRequest $req)
    {
      $NewOrder = new Order();
      $NewOrder-> date = $req->get('date');
      $NewOrder-> day = $req->get('day');
      $NewOrder-> city = $req->city;
      $NewOrder-> celivery_type = $req->get('celivery_type');
      $NewOrder-> place = $req->input('place');
      $NewOrder-> tel_2 = $req->input('tel_2');
      $NewOrder-> tel_1 = $req->input('tel_1');
      $NewOrder-> name_f_l = $req->input('name_f_l');
      $NewOrder-> b_number = $req->input('b_number');
      $NewOrder-> street = $req->street;
      $NewOrder-> entrance = $req->input('entrance');
      $NewOrder-> flat = $req->input('flat');
      $NewOrder-> floor = $req->input('floor');
      $NewOrder-> elevator = $req->input('elevator');
      $NewOrder-> _private = $req->input('_private');
      $NewOrder-> parking = $req->input('parking');
      $NewOrder-> hour_for_guests = $req->input('hour_for_guests');
      $NewOrder-> my_arrival = $req->input('my_arrival');
      $NewOrder-> until = $req->input('until');
      $NewOrder-> description = $req->input('description');
      $NewOrder->save();
    }
}
```

Город и улица получить

```
class CityStreetDataController extends Controller
{
    public function getCity()
    {
      $Citys = City_List::get();
      $Orders = Order::get();
      return view('Order',['Citys'=>$Citys,'Orders'=>$Orders]);
    }
    public function getStreet($id)
    {
      return json_encode(Street_List::get()->where("city_id",$id)->pluck("street","id"));
    }
}
```

Выбор города

```
<select name="city" id="city" class="font-weight-bold form-control text-primary js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control" value="hruakho" style="width: 152px; direction: rtl;">
          <option data-hidden="true">no city</option>
          <option></option>
        <option>no city</option>
        @foreach ($Citys as  $city)
        <option  value="{{$city->id }}">{{ ucfirst($city->city) }}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
```

Выбор улицы

```
<select name="street" id="street" class="font-weight-bold form-control text-primary js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control" value="hruakho" style="width: 152px; direction: rtl;">
```

JQuery Ajax

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ()
            {
                    jQuery('select[name="city"]').on('change',function(){
                       var id = jQuery(this).val();
                       if(id)
                       {
                          jQuery.ajax({
                             url: '/StreetList/'+id,
                             type : "GET",
                             dataType : "json",
                             success:function(data)
                             {
                                console.log(data);
                                jQuery('select[name="street"]').empty();
                                jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                                   $('select[name="street"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                                });
                             }
                          });
                       }
                       else
                       {
                          $('select[name="street"]').empty();
                       }
                    });
            });
        </script>[![ta][1]][1]
```

Маршруты

```
Route::post('/Order/Execute', 'OrderController@AddNewOrder')->name('OrderSender');
Route::get('Order/Ordering', 'CityStreetDataController@getCity')->name('Ordering');
Route::get('/StreetList/{id}', 'CityStreetDataController@getStreet');
```

[Таблица заказов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuRFx.png)

Comment: Ну тут два варианта, либо указываете название улицы и города в value, а id храните в data атрибуте, либо перед сохранением в базу, вытаскиваете из базы данные по этим id

Comment: спосибо большое!! все роботает!!!